# Using JSS Sitecore 9.1 with scaled architecture

Tags: jss

I have installed Sitecore 9.1 XP scaled(XP1) topology so I have sitecore.cm ,sitecore.cd and other app roles installed (REP, PRC, etc).
I have configured JSS and am able to use it with sitecore.cm .

My query: Is there a process to expose JSS content using sitecore.cd. , as mobile team needs sitecore content I have exposed it with JSS. If so, can you please share the steps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow next steps:

1.Extract the server components Sitecore package with an unzip tool such as 7-zip

2.Extract the inner package.zip the same way. Ignore any unzip warnings about sc_*.txt files.

3. In the resulting items, deploy all of the items in the files folder to your CD server's webroot: App_Config, bin, sitecore, and Views.
   Congratulations, your CD server is ready to host JSS apps.

More information you find here: https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/getting-started/jss-server-install

Comment: Thank you Vlad , worked like rocket

Comment: Please mark as correct